# Docker-compose Error http: invalid Host header, [Internal] booting buildkit

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am running docker version 20.10.24 on a linux server (ubuntu 22). Everything was working fine for all apps i deployed to it using docker-compose file. Since yesterday all my apps giving the same error when trying to deploy. Instead of building apps docker-compose building or booting buildkit (don't know what it is and how it appeared out of blue). When i build and run directly with docker but without compose then apps are running fine. Its something to do with docker-compose

```
#1 [internal] booting buildkit
#1 pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1
#1 pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1 14.3s done
#1 creating container buildx_buildkit_default
#1 29.94 time="2023-10-06T09:12:05Z" level=warning msg="using host network as the defaul#1 creating container buildx_buildkit_default 15.7s done
time="2023-10-06T09:12:05Z" level=warning msg="using host network as the default"
#1 29.94 time="2023-10-06T09:12:05Z" level=warning msg="skipping containerd worker, as \"/run/containerd/containerd.sock\" does not exist"
#1 29.94 dtime="2023-10-06T09:12:05Z" level=info msg="found 1 workers, default=\"vqmalxhq8nkhwzm81d798d5q9\""
#1 29.94 `time="2023-10-06T09:12:05Z" level=warning msg="currently, only the default worker can be used."
#1 29.94 \time="2023-10-06T09:12:05Z" level=info msg="running server on /run/buildkit/buildkitd.sock"
#1 29.94 time="2023-10-06T09:12:05Z" level=warning msg="skipping containerd worker, as \"/run/containerd/containerd.sock\" does not exist"
#1 29.94 time="2023-10-06T09:12:05Z" level=warning msg="currently, only the default worker can be used."
#1 29.94 time="2023-10-06T09:12:05Z" level=warning msg="currently, only the default worker can be used."
#1 29.94 
#1 ERROR: http: invalid Host header
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem occurs on snap docker revision `2904` You can check the revision by:

```
snap info docker
```

Looking at the result the last line `installed:  20.10.24  (2904)  135MB`
Ref. [docker version 20.10.24](https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/20.10/#201024)

You must downgrade to docker revision `2893`:

```
sudo snap refresh --revision=2893 docker
```

And freeze the docker version:

```
sudo snap refresh --hold=forever docker
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
snap refresh --stable docker
```

to switch to the stable channel.

Or use:

```
sudo snap refresh --revision=2893 docker
```

to switch to specific revision.

Follow the link that helped solve my problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77296158/22113956